# AppHarbor test deployment with separate RavenDb

Tags: ravendb, appharbor

I'd like to be able to deploy my github 'dev' and 'production' branches to different AppHarbor hosted applications. To achieve this I've set up an application slug on github. The two applications are now correctly deployed based on the related branch but the problem is that they share the same RavenHQ database.

What needs to be done so that each application has its own database (for testing purposes) ?

Note: I'm using the bronze/free plan for both AppHarbor and RavenHQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running two separate AppHarbor applications, you should just add the RavenDB add-on to both and you should be fine.